# Dropping rows where number of cases is greater that population size

Tags: r, drop

I have merged health data (cases) with population data. In some instances, the number of cases (n) is greater than the population size (N). I will need to drop these rows.

What is the most efficient way to do this in R? For example: where n > N, replace n with 0?

Comment: Please include some sample data, eg using the `dput()` function.

Comment: `df$n[df$n > df$N] <- 0` will replace `n` in a data.frame called `df` whenever that row's `n > N`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To drop rows

df = df[df$n < df$N,]

## for replacement

df[df$n > df$N,"n"] = 0